# Sorting by price in Mongo Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, backend

Trying to sort assets based on price.

**blade.php**

```
<form action="/assets/search/" method="GET" class="form-inline">
@csrf
    <div class="searchByPrice pt-3">
       <p class="font-weight-bold">Search By Price</p>
       <label for="price">Volume</label>
       <input type="range" min="0" max="500000" id="price" step="100" name="price"
        oninput="outputUpdate(value)">
       <output for="price" id="volume">250000</output>
       <script>
           function outputUpdate(vol) {
               document.querySelector('#volume').value = vol;
           }
       </script>
     </div>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
public function show(Request $request, $_id)
    {
        $query = Asset::query();
        if ($p = $request->price) {
            $query->where('price', '<', $p);
        }
        $assets =  $query->get();
        return view('assets::assets',compact('assets'));
    }
```

**dd();**

[DD($request->price);](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDDgE.png)

I'm not getting the desired results. Any Solutions? Or are there any alternative solutions for sorting by price in Laravel mongo?

Comment: what is the value of dd($request->price);

Comment: Its the value from range

Comment: Could it be because I'm getting a string in output? If yes then how to convert?

Comment: i want to see what the value is, "Its the value from range", i do not know how it is formatted.

Comment: I have attached a screenshot shot in question at last

Comment: That code should work what is your problem?

Comment: Yes, It should. I also converted output into an int32 but still not working. Is there any other code you'd like to see? I think I have added all the relevant code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was doing wrong is that I needed to return the query inside the `if()` statement. Like this:

```
public function show(Request $request, $_id)
{
  $query = Asset::query();
  if ($p = $request->price) {
    $query->where('price', '<', $p);
    $assets =  $query->get();
    return view('assets::assets',compact('assets'));
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in Request Post/Get Method Form Pass sort data element_name in ascending/ descending order

```
....
    "sort": {
        "price": "asc"
    }
....
```

Function In Laravel

```
$query = \App\Models\mongo\Log::query();
// Apply sorting
$sort = $request->input('sort', []);
foreach ($sort as $field => $order) {
  $query->orderBy($field, $order);
}

$data = $query->get();
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and explain how it works or why it is better.